# How to compare and replace keys inside nested dictionaries according to what user inputs

Tags: python

```
H = {'PC1': ['01:01:01:01:01:01', '192.168.0.1', '200', {}],
     'PC2': ['02:02:02:02:02:02',
             '192.168.0.2',
             '200',
             {'192.168.0.1': ('01:01:01:01:01:01', 1390710916.226)}],
     'PC3': ['03:03:03:03:03:03', '192.168.0.3', '200', {}]}
```

In this dictionary I want the user to input four values `host_id`, `IP`, `MAC` and `time`.

So in first turn user inputs `PC1` as `host_id`, `192.168.0.1` as `IP`, `01:01:01:01:01:01` as `MAC`, and `200` as `time`

Note inside the tuple are MAC and time (this is not the time as given above but called though time.time() function). Means key inside a nested dictionary is associated with tuple.

Now if in next turn a user inputs same IP but different MAC, e.g., `192.168.0.1` as `IP` and `04:04:04:04:04:04` as `MAC`, I need to check nested dictionary of all `PC`s so that if someone has old `MAC` and `time` (for the key) it should be replaced with latest information (new `MAC` and `time`), but if and only if (`time` already associated with the key (`IP`) + 200) is less than current time (`time.time()`). Otherwise I will delete the relevant key from nested dictionary of that host.

So after I entered new information for `PC1` as `host_id=PC1`, `IP=192.168.0.1`, `MAC=04:04:04:04:04:04`, and `time=200`, `PC2` would update because only it has relevant key in its nested dictionary.

Output will be:

```
H = {'PC1': ['01:01:01:01:01:01', '192.168.0.1', '200', {}],
     'PC2': ['02:02:02:02:02:02',
             '192.168.0.2',
             '200',
             {'192.168.0.1': ('04:04:04:04:04:04', 1390864671.669904)}],
     'PC3': ['03:03:03:03:03:03', '192.168.0.3', '200', {}]}
```

Note: there can be many `PC`s, and user can input any `host`. So I want to check inside dictionaries of all other `host`s.

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but it sounds like you're trying to search a dictionary by some subcomponent of its values. You usually don't want to do this. Use a dictionary keyed by that subcomponent instead. (Or, if you have some other reason the dictionary needs to be keyed the way it is, use an "index dictionary" for each "alternate key" that maps the alternate key to the key in the main dictionary.) That not only makes your code simpler, it also turns a lot of linear and quadratic operations into constant (in other words, changes things from "way too slow" to "fast").

Comment: What I want is search for a particular key inside nested dictionaries not in main dictionary and replace that key with new key( I mean key name would be same but values would change)

Comment: My point is that your data structure design will make this inherently (a) complicated and (b) slow. It's still _doable_, but it would be much better to use the right data structure in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to translate your English description into Python:

> I need to check nested dictionary of all PCs

```
for key, (mac, ip, time, sub_dict) in H.items():
```

> … so that if someone has old MAC and time (for the key)

I think here you want to search in each `sub_dict`, which maps `ip`s to `(mac, time)` pairs, to see if any of them match the new entry's `mac` and `time`:

```
    for sub_ip, (sub_mac, sub_time) in sub_dict.items():
        if (sub_mac, sub_time) == (user_mac, user_time):
```

> … if and only if (time already associated with the key (IP) + 200) is less than current time (time.time())

```
            if sub_time + 200 < time.time():
```

> … it should be replaced with latest information (new MAC and time)

```
                sub_dict[sub_ip] = (user_mac, user_time)
```

> … Otherwise I will delete the relevant key from nested dictionary of that host.

```
            else:
                del sub_dict[sub_ip]
```

However, this runs into a problem. Replacing the value for a key while iterating over a dictionary is fine, but adding or removing keys is not. You may get an exception, or incorrect results, or, worst of all, correct results most of the time but incorrect results every so often.

You can fix that by iterating over a *copy* of the `dict`, or by building a new replacement `dict`, e.g., using a comprehension.

Normally, I'd suggest a comprehension, but in this case, your condition is so complicated that might get hard to read, so let's use a copy instead.

```
for key, (mac, ip, time, sub_dict) in H.items():
    for sub_ip, (sub_mac, sub_time) in dict(sub_dict).items():
        if (sub_mac, sub_time) == (user_mac, user_time):
            if sub_time + 200 < time.time():
                sub_dict[sub_ip] = (user_mac, user_time)
            else:
                del sub_dict[sub_ip]
```

I'm not sure I understood your description correctly, but even if I didn't, this should serve as a template for you to write the code you need.

As I mentioned in a comment, this would all be a lot simpler—and faster—if you used a more sensible data structure. If you want to look things up, the thing you want to loop up should be a *key* in a dictionary, not a *value*. If there can be multiple values for each key, that's not a problem; just use a dict whose values are sets. If you need to look things up *both* ways, you can use one of the various "bidirectional dict" implementations on PyPI, or use "index maps", separate dictionaries that map each kind of "alternate key" to the appropriate "primary key". If I understood what you were trying to do and why, I could give a more specific suggestion, but hopefully this is enough to get you thinking about your data structure design.